# Next Cloud (docker) - "Cannot create or write into the data directory" eurror

Tags: docker, ubuntu-server, nextcloud

in my ubuntu server I run a docker container using this command:

```
sudo docker run -it --name next-cloud-01 -d -p 8080:80 -v "/media/usr/dati:/var/www/html/data/usr/files" nextcloud
```

`/media/usr/dati` is a mount point for my sdb1 HD, and `/var/www/html/data/usr/files` is where Next Cloud saves the user data. I specified this volume because I want that Next Cloud manages all the data using my sdb1 HD.

unfortunately when I try to configure Next Cloud, something wrong happens, and from the login web page, I can't do anything (see the attached screenshot).

[image]

if I don't use the `-v` option this error doesn't exist, so I think that, maybe, the issue is something like permissions, .. it seems that Next Cloud is not able to write on sdb1 HD, but I don't know why. how can I solve thi issue?